# Why do I have to set a source `.asm` file's `Properties > General > Item Type` to ` Microsoft Macro Assembler` ...?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

Why do I have to set a source `.asm` file's `Properties > General > Item Type` to  `Microsoft Macro Assembler`, even though I had already selected for the project node, the option `Build dependencies > Build Customization > masm`.

Comment: What is happening that causes you to have this belief?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The assembler is not invoked because the default option for the file's `Properties  > General > Item type` is `Does not participate in build`.

Comment: It may depend on what order you do them in.  Iirc, if you set the customization first, everything works as expected.  But if you add a masm file to the project and *then* set the customization, you either need to drop/re-add the file, or set the item type manually.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd That's not possible. The option `Microsoft Macro Assembler` does not exist in `Item Type` if you don't first select `Build dependencies > Build customizations > masm` for the project.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd In other words, you always have to set `Build dependencies > Build customizations > masm`  and then `Properties > General > Item Type` to  `Microsoft Macro Assembler` later, which seems superfluous to me.

Comment: The fact that Microsoft Macro Assembler does not exist in Item Type does not prevent you from being able to add an item with an asm extension to the project.  Adding the customization *after* you've added the item doesn't automatically go back and properly set the item types for existing items.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Maybe I didn't express myself clearly. There is no way you can set up the Item Type before the Customization at the project level, simply because the option `Microsoft Macro Assembler` is not there. You have to set up first the Customization to `masm` and then the item type to `Microsoft Macro Assembler` which is redundant.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Now I think I'm understanding what you wrote [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68611898/why-do-i-have-to-set-a-source-asm-files-properties-general-item-type-t#comment121259314_68611898). But why  doesn't VS update automatically the item type in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on which version of Visual Studio you are using, but I recall what seemed like a one time option to auto-select masm for .asm file with one of the versions. After dealing with multiple versions of Visual Studio and having issues with some versions, I manually set the properties for each .asm file to use a custom build tool (also turn off does not participate in build as commented by John Kalane), which is working for all the versions I have (VS2005, VS2010, VS2015, VS2019).

32 bit debug build, for release build /Zi is not needed:

```
command line: ml /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\example.obj example.asm
outputs: $(OutDir)\example.obj
```

64 bit debug build, for release build /Zi is not needed:

```
command line: ml64 /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\example.obj example.asm
outputs: $(OutDir)\example.obj
```